# Using bash history to its fullest potential - a thorough, fast solution

Tags: bash, history

I am thoroughly dependant upon `ctrl-r` to be able to reproduce many things I do on the command line.   If I remember any part of any command that I used in the past I can bring up that old command by typing `ctrl-r` and typing the parts of the command that I remember.

A while back I was frustrated that each time I closed a terminal session I would lose my history, so I added these commands to my `.bashrc` :

```
export HISTIGNORE=lst::top:ssh*:cd*  # don't put these in history
export HISTCONTROL=erasedups    # no duplicate entries
export HISTSIZE=50000           # big big history
shopt -s histappend             # append to history, don't overwrite it
# Save and reload the history after each command finishes
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Once I did that I discovered that my life was utterly enjoyable, pulling up commands from years ago on a moments notice.   However, as you can imagine, after a couple of years my terminal is starting to slow down.  Every time I enter a command I need to wait for the big history to be updated.   I'm at the point now where having to wait a second each time I type something is getting a little too annoying.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to maintain a thorough searchable history without experiencing the delay caused by doing a history update after every command?

Comment: Maybe make a key combination that will reload the file. From my experience i seldom need a command from one terminal in the other as normally i'm using them for different things.

Comment: I don't think the `history -r` is necessary in `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Your shell reads the history file on startup, at which point `history -a` should be sufficient to keep the in-memory list up-to-date until you write to disk upon exiting the shell.

Comment: I removed the `history -r`, which I'll need to adjust to because I often jump from shell to shell (connected to different machines) to run the same commands.  However, I did find that there was a significant improvement in speed.  Secondly, I discovered that using the` export PROMPT_COMMAND=` as above resulted in `PROMPT_COMMAND = "history -a; history -r; history -a; history -r;"`.  Fixing this to just run the history commands once also sped things up significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better served by keeping a collections of tips & tricks for yourself. Make a directory in your home dir called `~/.notes/` or the like and add little files in there when you learn something new.

`~/.notes/bash_tricks`

```
* seq outputs a list of numbers
  seq 5 --> 1 2 3 4 5
  seq 5 10 --> 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

`~/.notes/ssh`

```
* Make an ssh key using ssh-keygen
```

These you can tar up and save forever using whatever method you like. Dropbox, thumb drive, whatever.

If you look at your history every few days for inspiration you can probably reduce the size of it and get back the performance you want.